# SSRS : How to repeat header row of a table on each page that is embedded in a LIST?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a SSRS report that has a list which includes two embedded tables.

For these tables if I set the header rows to repeat on each page, I get an error `"All tablix member elements in a TablixColumnHierarchy must have the RepeatOnNewPage Property set to false".`

How do I fix this and make the headers repeat on each page?

Thank you.

Comment: Check out this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/6d6ad0d2-439e-458a-a64a-e427ca628a9e/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. In design mode while editing the rdl file, at bottom of the editor you will find `Row Groups` and `Column Groups` (left and right, respectively). Beside `Column Groups` you will find one arrow button <kbd>▼</kbd> (this arrow button is at the right side of the column groups portion). Click on this arrow button.
2. Check `Advanced Mode`
3. In the `RowGroups` section you will find '(Static)' and '(Details)'. click on/highlight `(Static)` and press <kbd>F4</kbd> (to check its properties on the `Properties` window.)
4. Set `Keep With Group` to `After`
5. Set `Repeat On New Page` to `True`
6. Go back to table, right-click on the row header (the grey bar), and select to `Tablix Properties`.
7. Check on `Repeat header columns on each page` and `repeat header column on each Row`. (Edit as of VS2012 at least he might mean `Repeat header rows on each page`)

Answer (score 0):

Its nothing but a property for the report named RepeatOnNewPage is false. If you click on the page header and go for page header properties

General --> Display header for this page -> Print on first page and print on last page(check all the boxes over here )and click ok

Run the report. This is done on report builder 3.0 .I am not sure which tool you are using.

Or you can follow this

Select the Tablix.

In the grouping pane, click on the small triangle and select "Advanced Mode" to show static members.

In the row group hierarchy, select the corresponding (static) item of the header row.

In the Properties grid:

set RepeatOnNewPage to True

Comment: Thanks for the reply Akarsh
 
but when i do that i get a different error `The tablix includes a table header or column with FixedHeader set to true. This is not allowed on data regions inside other data regions`
 
remember these tables are withing a list  which is the real issue i think.

Comment: Hey Did you click on the list which you created and the properties on side shows tablix. Then go to tablix properties ---> General --> "Repeat Header rows on each page"(this would show up in Rowheaders. Click on it). Click ok and run the report.Let me know what you see.

Comment: Akarsh i get the first error even if i try to set the RepeatOnEachPage for the list tablix

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/6d6ad0d2-439e-458a-a64a-e427ca628a9e/   this link would help you